# Accessing an Amazon RDS MySQL database from CodeIgniter leads a blank display

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter, amazon-rds

This is related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869442/codeigniter-1-72-and-php-5-3-29-compatible). I'm making it a new question because at this point I believe it's a database access issue.

Essentially, I've switched the database from a MySql sever to an Amazon RDS MySql server, due to server migration.  To summarize, I'm attempting to migrate a PHP site based on CodeIgniter (version 1.7.2) to a new server which has AmazonLinux as the OS. The previous server was Ubuntu, running PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.5 on Apache2. The PHP version on the new AmazonLinux server is 5.3.29, running on httpd.

The problem is, when I try to access the URL in the new server, I get a blank display. The code is stopping in system/core/CodeIgniter.php at this line:

```
$CI = new $class();
```

The last line of the application log is this:

```
DEBUG - 2015-04-25 17:17:58 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
```

So, it's happening around the database. I've also read that you get a blank display if it's a database issue due to an "@" being used for database-related messages.

These are the settings in database.php:

```
$active_group = "default";
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = "xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$db['default']['username'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['password'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['database'] = "xxxxx";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['port'] = 3306;
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = "TRUE";
// $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "/opt/xxxxx/cachedb/";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

I also tried it without the port specified (as it's set up on the current production site) as well as with the port specified at the end of the url:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = "xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306";
```

But I'm still getting the blank display.

We have a Java/Tomcat application running on the same server that is able to access the RDS database, using the same url, name and password, so it doesn't appear to be an issue of security groups.

Any thoughts on what the problem might be?  and if so how to solve?

Edit 1: I've tracked down the problem - not surprisingly, it's the database driver. It fails when calling this function: 
system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php:  function db_pconnect()

The question is, can I just copy in a more recent driver into this older version of CodeIgnitor and it will miraculously work? I'll try that experiment tomorrow. Otherwise, we might be looking at an upgrade. Grim, but it should theoretically work, since it will have an up-to-date driver. Right?

Comment: I think there is no need having port in hostname since there is specific option for port. But what would happen if you set `mysqli` dbdriver instead?

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but no luck. I turned the debug level to 4 in the old environment, and the log statements show it gets beyond the "Database Driver Class Initialized" statement to a "Session Class Initialized" statement. I'm going to delve into the source and try to isolate the exact line where it dies.

Comment: See what effort would be required [to upgrade](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrading.html) application to newer version (at least 2.2.1).

Comment: I'll do it if I have to, but it would be nice to know what's causing the problem. My concern is, what if I go through the effort and it still doesn't work?

Comment: Good point tho. I searched bit SOF and there is already planty of questions similar to this one (query example "codeigniter amazon rds") and some of them seems to have solved issue. But you should check them and see what could work for you. I would go that way. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: No, you've been extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a database access issue. Specifically, the version of PHP on the new server turned out to not support deprecated calls to php-mysql APIs (e.g. @mysql_pconnect or @mysql_connect)

The solution was to

1) Download the mysql library which supports the legacy calls. In the case of AmazonLinux, this is accomplished as follows:

```
sudo yum install php-mysql
```

2) Find where the library was downloaded e.g.

```
find / -name mysql.so
```

This may have been shown in the install as well, but that is a way to find it anytime. YMMV, but in my case, the library name was:

```
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mysql.so
```

3) Change php.ini (as shown in phpinfo when called from a php page on the httpd/apached server) as follows:

a) change "extension_dir" to show where the mysql.so is installed:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules"
```

b) Then add the following lines:

```
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Reboot apache and you should be good to go.

Note: the specific legacy call not supported, which is part of of the version of CodeIgnitor I'm working with, was this:

```
   return @mysql_pconnect($this->hostname, $this->username, $this-// etc.
```

The php error log showed this error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in xxx.php on line xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow 3306 port in your server. I will only possible when you have WHM access. Otherwise contact with your server administrator.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my response, it was an issue with a legacy library not being available.